# How to make collapsible filter on e-shop

Tags: javascript, html, content-management-system

i work on e-shop that has too much filter options. So it's very uncomfortable to use on phones. The filter has 8 categories with so many options. But there is a little complication it's made by CMS and I have very strict options to work with.
Here is the question. I need to collapse the main 8 categories but it's divided into divs for example theres Price and under is slider. So i need that the user on mobile device will see only Price and some kind of plus or anything to show the slider. I need to do it only by JavaScript in head or body.
Here is example of code I am speaking of:

#### Here is the example of code "Cena" is "Price"

[image]

#### Here is how it looks like

[image]

Comment: please add your code as a code bock not images

Comment: I have no way to copy the code as whole. sorry